# SQL Server Error:"SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I got this wired error message while debugging the following code:

```
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT  1
                    FROM    defs WITH(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   defaultname = @DEFAULT_CURRENCY
                    AND defaultvalue= @currency)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT  1
                    FROM    supp WITH(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   pint    = @ID
                    AND currency= @currency)
           THEN "NOT VALID."
```

I couldn't find anything wrong with my code regarding to the error message. Moreover, this error message disappear when I changed **'AND'** to **'OR'**.

```
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT  1
                    FROM    defs WITH(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   defaultname = @DEFAULT_CURRENCY
                    AND defaultvalue= @currency)
    OR NOT EXISTS(  SELECT  1
                    FROM    supp WITH(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   pint    = @ID
                    AND currency= @currency)
            THEN "NOT VALID."
```

I need to use 'AND' condition, but how to remove the error?

(All @ variable in the code snippet is not table variable.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that error if for the part of the code you shown? and not for other pieces of codes you didn't show?

Comment: Show your actual code.   WHEN NOT EXISTS isn't valid TSQL.   If this is a fragment of a CASE statement, then know that CASE statements return values and cannot be used for control of flow.   So THEN PRINT .. would be invalid.

Comment: @Farhęg Yes, otherwise the error message shouldn't disappear when I change the code. (I could still replicate this error by just changing the code as I described above.)

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry, I made mistake. The case statement is used for validating data and returning a string as warning message. So THEN follows a string, not PRINT. But this is not my question.

Comment: Why the NOLOCK hints everywhere? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows randomly?

Comment: @SeanLange The NOLOCK thing is our code conversion. :)  It's not duplicate, I do need to check the currency value from different table.

Comment: @AbnerChou can you put the complete query?  Changing `and` with `or` maybe is returning different values in your main query and maybe the problem can be there.  I think those sub-queries are OK.

Comment: You need to show more of your query for anybody to understand the issue.

Comment: @aSharma I will create a sample code which could replicate the error.

Comment: You missed my point. The NOLOCK hint is far more sinister than just dirty reads. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. Here are a couple of articles on the topic. There are plenty more. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, I do have to read these articles.

Comment: is there a subquery in the else case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that one of your subqueries, but i don't think these subqueries are the one that give the error.
If you use and 'exist' ( or 'not exist' ) you can also use TOP 1, because you only need to check one row.

This means you can use:

```
WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1
                    FROM    defs WITH(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   defaultname = @DEFAULT_CURRENCY
                    AND defaultvalue= @currency)
    OR NOT EXISTS(  SELECT TOP 1  1
                    FROM    supp WITH(NOLOCK)
                    WHERE   pint    = @ID
                    AND currency= @currency)
```

But this is not what is causing your error.
This example code does that same and works fine:

```
declare @table1 table (
    id int,
    value nvarchar(100)
)

declare @subquery table (
    id int,
    value nvarchar(100)
)

insert into @table1 values (1, 'one')
insert into @table1 values (2, 'two')
insert into @table1 values (3, 'three')
insert into @subquery values (1, 'also one')
insert into @subquery values (3, 'also three')
insert into @subquery values (5, 'also five')


select * from @table1 sourceTable
where not exists (select 1 from @subquery where id = sourceTable.id)
     and not exists (select 1 from @subquery where value = sourceTable.value)
```

So I think it must be in another part of your query.

Comment: Thank you, yeah, the problem is from other part code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add some more parenthesis to make sure the operator precedence won't affect?

```
    WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT  1
                FROM    defs WITH(NOLOCK)
                WHERE   defaultname = @DEFAULT_CURRENCY
                AND defaultvalue= @currency))
AND (NOT EXISTS( SELECT  1
                FROM    supp WITH(NOLOCK)
                WHERE   pint    = @ID
                AND currency= @currency))
       THEN PRINT "NOT VALID."
```

Comment: Thanks Zee, I did. Still the same.